# Symfony 4 HTTP Cache Headers not same in profiler and browser

Tags: php, symfony, http, symfony4, http-caching

For a website development, I try to use Symfony 4 HTTP cache described in [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/http_cache.html).

I created an CacheKernel called in index.php like this :

```php
namespace App;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\HttpCache\HttpCache;

class CacheKernel extends HttpCache
{

}
```

```php
// index.php
$kernel = new Kernel($_SERVER['APP_ENV'], (bool) $_SERVER['APP_DEBUG']);
$kernel = new CacheKernel($kernel);
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
```

In homepage action:

```php
$response->setPublic();
$response->setMaxAge(3600);
$response->headers->addCacheControlDirective('must-revalidate', true);

return $response;
```

In profiler, headers are sets :

> cache-control "max-age=3600, must-revalidate, public"

But in browser, headers are not same, and I think cache is not stored :

> Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate, private

Have you got some ides to understand why headers are not same and why cache is not working please ?

And how can I make be sure cache is working, is there some logs ?

Thanks a lot for helping

Comment: Did you fix the issue? Same here with Smyfony 4.4, even with env prod. Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong as it pertains to your implementation but, if you are in `dev` environment the cache is disabled. This is so you can see changes immediately without having to manually clear the cache after every edit like older Symfony versions. The fact that the profiler shows what you would expect in `prod` tells me it is working and just being overridden due to being in `dev`.

Try switching to `prod` and

> look at the `X-Symfony-Cache` header for debugging information about
> cache hits and misses
>
> --https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/http_cache.html#expiration-caching

There is a log as well:

> The cache kernel has a special getLog() method that returns a string
> representation of what happened in the cache layer. In the development
> environment, use it to debug and validate your cache strategy:
>
> ```
> error_log($kernel->getLog());
> ```
>
> --https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/http_cache.html#symfony-reverse-proxy